# Wordpress add_action of wp_head for javascript / css files in plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress

For some reason, the following is not loading my JS and CSS into wordpress. This code is in an activated plugin, which is otherwise executing. Also, I checked and `wp_head` does exist in the theme.

```
add_action ( 'wp_head', 'lbIncludes');

function lbIncludes()  {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    wp_register_script('myScript',
    WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/myScript/myScript.bundle.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script('myScript');

    wp_register_style('myStyle', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/myScript/myScript.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('myStyle');
};
```

Bonus question - what's the appropriate way to make the script wait for jquery to load first?

Comment: Sigh. You can't enqueue on wp_head. Rather, you have to do it on an init action, such as:

add_action ( 'init', 'lbIncludes');

But I still can't get the css to appear.

Comment: Could it be the `};` in the last line? It should be `}`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to load jQuery before your scripts do this:

```
wp_register_script('myScript', WP_PLUGIN_URL . '/myScript/myScript.bundle.js', array('jquery') );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try hooking to wp_print_styles and wp_print_scripts. To ensure jQuery is loaded first add the $deps parameter when you [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script).